# mongodb replica set master "stateStr" : "REMOVED"

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-vpc

I have a mongodb replicaset running in a docker container (mongo:3.0.11) in a aws vpc (for this specific case just one node, primary).

This server is shutdown every night and started again in the next morning.

After a few months running seamlessly, I'm having a few errors in the past few weeks. Happens that once or twice a week the mongo startup fails.

`rs.status()` returns `stateStr: REMOVED`

and as error message: `errmsg : "Our replica set config is invalid or we are not a member of it"`

Looking at the mongo logs I have:

`2016-06-07T12:01:48.724+0000 W NETWORK  [ReplicationExecutor] getaddrinfo("database.my_vpc_dns.net") failed: Name or service not known`

When this error happens, a simple restart on the docker container will fix, but I'm struggling to understand what is causing this error to happen occasionally.

Comment: So when you restart the server that issue goes correct?

Comment: @error2007s if I restart the mongo docker container yes. The issue is gone. If I restart the server it's not guaranteed that the issue will be resolved, in most of the cases yes, but at some point in future, when the server startup again the same error can happen again. This error only happens at the server startup. But as I said, its occasionally, not on every server startup.

Comment: So you restart the server or you stop and start the server?

Comment: I stop the server (shutdown) by 8pm and start again next morning (7am). The mongodb docker container is started during the server startup process (/etc/rc.local script)

Comment: I guess this is happening due to your server IP address changing when you stop and start the EC2 instance. Had you assigned a Elastic IP to the server?

Comment: This is a private instance inside a vpc. It doesn't have a public ip, just a private IP which I believe never changes (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-ip-addressing.html#vpc-public-ip-addresses) I use route53 to map a internal DNS name to that private IP. I use that DNS name on the replicat set configs.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the replica loses the configuration when doing the restart. It is possible that the replica loses the reading of the DNS reason why it does not manage to raise when the server is started.

What you can do is to point to the machine directly through the domain.my-machine in the `Execute db.isMaster()` in primary to not restart.